# Generate an error message when the result of a command is empty

Tags: macros, ifthenelse, renewcommand

I have the following sample code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\defineSpecies}[2]{\csdef{spec@#1}{#2}}
\newrobustcmd{\spec}[1]{\csuse{spec@#1}}

\defineSpecies{h2o}{H$_2$O}

\begin{document}

\spec{h2o}
\spec{undefined}

\end{document}
```

My intention is to redefine `\spec{}` such that it prints an error message when it provides an empty output, for example for `\spec{undefined}` which is in fact undefined. Could you please help me how to achieve this goal?

Comment: First of look at chchem or chemmacros for H2O. Secondly, it is not clear what you mean by {} vs {undefined}, there are a lot of tools for you in etoolbox, fx csdefvoid and isblank

Comment: What about catching up "malicious" input like `\spec{h2o\endcsname\csname TeX}` ? :-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can test whether `\spec@#1` exists using `\ifcsname <csname>\endcsname`, and conditionally print a `\GenericError`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\defineSpecies}[2]{\csdef{spec@#1}{#2}}
\newrobustcmd{\spec}[1]{%
  \ifcsname spec@#1\endcsname% Specification exists
    \csuse{spec@#1}%
  \else% Specification does not exist
    \GenericError{}{Specification `#1' undefined}{}{}%
  \fi}

\defineSpecies{h2o}{H$_2$O}

\begin{document}

\spec{h2o}
\spec{undefined}% This will cause an error.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Excellent answer, thank you! This is exactly what I looked for.